# Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzij`

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try fix some feature of my app after update android studio 3.2.1. But seem i get more error. When i try rebuild app. I got this messenger:

```
Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzij`.
```

But, my build.gradle (Module:app) and build.gradle (Project) look fine. 
Here my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 7x
        versionName "1.0.7x"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    implementation('com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.8.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.1.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/xxx.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And, here my build.gradle (project) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
//    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven{
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried find some solution for this issue. But i find nothing. So, anyone can help me ?

Comment: Get rid of `play-services` bundle and only pull in what you need. **All GMS dependencies need to have the same version until v15. You have v12 of everything and then v16 of maps.** Get rid of jars with okhttp and okio and get them from maven to avoid potential conflicts. And, for the love of all holy, organize your dependencies into paragraphs, no wonder you can't see through this hot mess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might need to remove `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`

And replace it with

```
 implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1") {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
```

BEFORE [image]
AFTER[image]

Comment: Some people just underrate other peoples answers!

Comment: there is a person trolling me on stack overflow immediately marking my answers as not useful

Comment: Dear Joash, i don't know who try to troll you. But, thanks a lot to you help ( i fixed it, but still thanks) and upvote for you.

Comment: I have the same error but the above solution is not working for me. @joash Can u plz add more explaination into your answer?

Comment: @NeelDsouza,  the idea is you try to see which library(ies) is included twice or more(which could be your case) and remove it from that plugin which comes with it by using *exclude*. Gradle has ways you can list included libraries https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips

Answer (score 1):

Updating my 'com.google.android.gms' dependencies to the latest version fixed my issue. You can update your dependencies from `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies (Click update)` or directly chnge to the version you require in your build.gradle file like below

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0"
```